# Splitting up a 3 rows evenly in a column for a table HTML

Tags: html, css

So I have the following table that I have created using HTML and CSS: [image] However, I would like the three pieces of information under Harvesting to be split divided evenly so that each cell takes the same amount of space in the Harvesting column. Right now, the table cell with electroflocculation takes up the space of 2 cells because I assigned it to temporarly do so using the rowspan attribute when it should ideally be taking up the space of 4/3 of a cell,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12 px;
    color: #111111;}
  th {
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #111111;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
  }

  .ExtractionConversion {
    background-color: #f4cccc;
  }
  .Cultivation {
    background-color: #d9ead3;
  }
  .Harvesting {
    background-color: #fce5cd;
  }
  .Dewatering {
    background-color: #c9daf8;
  }
  .Extraction {
    background-color: #d9d2e9;
  }
  .Conversion {
    background-color: #fff2cc;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width=800 height=100 style="text-align: center" padding="10">
  <thead>
    <th>Cultivation</th>
    <th>Harvesting</th>
    <th>Dewatering</th>
    <th>Extraction</th>
    <th>Conversion</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="Cultivation";>Photobioreactor</td>
      <td class="Harvesting">Centrifugation</td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="Dewatering">Heat Drying</td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="Extraction">Wet Solvent Extraction</td>
      <td class="Conversion">Decarboxylation<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Harvesting">Electrocoagulation</td>
      <td class="Conversion">Transesterfication</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="Harvesting">Electroflocculation</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="Dewatering">Speed Drying</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="ExtractionConversion">HTL-CHG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="ExtractionConversion">Pyrolysis</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert another table in that  and style the cells, adding borders to get it done. It's not pretty but it works.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12 px;
    color: #111111;}
  th {
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #111111;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
  }

  .ExtractionConversion {
    background-color: #f4cccc;
  }
  .Cultivation {
    background-color: #d9ead3;
  }
  .Harvesting {
    background-color: #fce5cd;
  }
  .Dewatering {
    background-color: #c9daf8;
  }
  .Extraction {
    background-color: #d9d2e9;
  }
  .Conversion {
    background-color: #fff2cc;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width=800 height=100 style="text-align: center" padding="10">
  <thead>
    <th>Cultivation</th>
    <th>Harvesting</th>
    <th>Dewatering</th>
    <th>Extraction</th>
    <th>Conversion</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="Cultivation";>Photobioreactor</td>
      <td class="Harvesting">Centrifugation</td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="Dewatering">Heat Drying</td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="Extraction">Wet Solvent Extraction</td>
      <td class="Conversion">Decarboxylation<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Harvesting">Electrocoagulation</td>
      <td class="Conversion">Transesterfication</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="Harvesting">Electroflocculation</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="Dewatering">Speed Drying</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="ExtractionConversion">HTL-CHG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="ExtractionConversion">Pyrolysis</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table width=800 height=100 style="text-align: center" padding="10">
  <thead>
    <th>Cultivation</th>
    <th>Harvesting</th>
    <th>Dewatering</th>
    <th>Extraction</th>
    <th>Conversion</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="Cultivation";>Photobioreactor</td>
      <td rowspan="4" class="Harvesting" style="padding:0;">
      <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% height=100% style="text-align: center">
       <tr>
        <td class="Harvesting" style="border-bottom:2px solid white;">Centrifugation</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="Harvesting" style="border-bottom:2px solid white;">Electrocoagulation</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="Harvesting">Electroflocculation</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
      
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="Dewatering">Heat Drying</td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="Extraction">Wet Solvent Extraction</td>
      <td class="Conversion">Decarboxylation<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     
      <td class="Conversion">Transesterfication</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
        <td rowspan="2" class="Dewatering">Speed Drying</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="ExtractionConversion">HTL-CHG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="ExtractionConversion">Pyrolysis</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<br>



<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful and greatly appreciated that you not only told me how to do it but also that you went ahead and even showed it to me.

Comment: @MathewJacob No problem at all ;) You can always upvote it and accept it as the answer :D